# Haskell -- how to use multiple modules in the same file?

Tags: haskell, module

Sorry this is a dumb question, but I cannot figure out how to put multiple modules in the same file. Suppose the file is named *A.hs*. If I put module *B* first, i.e.

```
module B where ...
module A where ...
```

it complains that it expected *A* when I run "ghci A" (It's not top-level, so I don't want to call "ghci A.hs"). The other way around, and it complains "parse error on input module").

There's a related bug here, http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2428 . Is there actually no way to get this, even if the other module is only used locally?

Comment: +1 good question, although the answer is essentially "you can't"

Comment: Can you briefly say why one would want this?

Comment: @Tarrasch it was primarily to work around name conflicts, when defining two record types with the same field names.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot have multiple modules in the same file. The bug you linked to is just about the error message given by GHC not being clear about this.

However, if you're using Cabal, you can still control the visibility of modules by putting the modules you want visible to users in the `Exposed-Modules` section, and putting any internal modules in `Other-Modules`.

Answer (score 8):

I found the following [bug report](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2551).

Which refers to this [mailing list item](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2008-August/046504.html), which states:

```
No, that's not possible because haskell will use the module name A.B.C to look the module up in path A/B/C.[l]hs.
So using modules
module A where
..
module B where
the compiler could only find one of them. (naming the file A.hs or B.hs)
You have to use one file for each module
```

So, I guess the answer is no.

Comment: the replies to that post point out that it is a GHC specific limitation, the spec does not mandate it