# Exporting multiple modules in one file

Tags: haskell, import, module

I need to export two modules in a single Haskell file. Right now, I have

```
module name (important,functions) where
module nameForTesting where

-- the code is here
```

however, it gives me this error:

```
filename.hs:5:1: error: parse error on input ‘module’
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: A file belongs to one module. You can however reimport a module, and export a subset.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Could you please explain what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you can not have multiple modules in the same file. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6922573/67579) seems to confirm this.

What you could do however is create a second module, that *re-exports* some functions. So we first make a file `NameForTesting.hs` with:

```
-- NameForTesting.hs
module NameForTesting where

important :: Int
important = 42

functions :: Int -> Int
functions = (42 +)

foo :: Int
foo = 21
```

Then we can construct a second file `Name.hs` that imports the `NameForTesting` module, but only exports `important` and `functions`:

```
-- Name.hs
module Name(important, functions) where

import NameForTesting
```

The `Name` module will here only export `important` and `functions` that are imported from the `NameForTesting` module.

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between *defining* a module and *exporting* names from that module; they are two separate steps.

A file can only define a single module. However, you can export names imported from other modules as part of that module. For example,

```
module MyModule (foo, bar) where

import OtherModule (bar) -- Let's say bar :: Int -> String

foo :: Int -> Int
foo x = x + 3
```

`MyModule` does not define `bar`; rather, it imports it from `OtherModule`, then exports it as part of itself. Users of `MyModule` then have access to `bar` without explicitly importing `OtherModule`:

```
import MyModule

main = putStrLn (bar (foo 9))
```